# Group by with where query on Pandas Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, group-by

I have dataset consists of categorical and numerical columns. 
For instance: salary dataset

columns: `['job', 'country_origin', 'age', 'salary', 'degree','marital_status']`

four categorical columns and two numerical columns and I want to use three aggregate functions:

```
cat_col = ['job', 'country_origin','degree','marital_status']
num_col = [ 'age', 'salary']
aggregate_function = ['avg','max','sum']
```

Currently, I have my Python code that using raw query, while my objective is to get the group-by query results from all combinations from lists above:

my query: `"SELECT cat_col[0], aggregate_function[0](num_col[0]) from DB where marital_status = 'married' groub by cat_col[0]"`

So queries are:

```
q1 = select job, avg(age) from DB where marietal_status='married' groub by job
q2 = select job, avg(salary) from DB where marietal_status='married' groub by job

etc
```

I used `for loop` to get the result from all combinations.

My problem is, I want to change that query to Pandas query. I've spent a couple of hours but could not solve it.

Pandas has a different way to querying data.

Sample dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['programmer', 'US', 28,4000, 'master','unmarried'], 
                             ['data scientist', 'UK', 30,5000, 'PhD','unmarried'],
                             ['manager', 'US', 48,9000, 'master','married']]),
                   columns=[['job', 'country_origin', 'age', 'salary', 'degree','marital_status']])
```

Comment: Could you include a sample of the Dataframe?

Comment: @DanielMesejo I put just a sample of dataframe. The real data is on my Postgre database. While using raw query is fine for me, but I need to change it using Pandas to make my operation easier. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First import the libaries

```
import pandas as pd
```

Build the sample dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame( { 
    "job" : ["programmer","data scientist","manager"] , 
    "country_origin" : ["US","UK","US"],
    "age": [28,30,48],
    "salary": [4000,5000,9000],
    "degree": ["master","PhD","master"],
    "marital_status": ["unmarried","unmarried","married"]} )
```

apply the where clause, save as a new dataframe (not necessary, but easier to read), you can of course use the filtered df inside the groupby

```
married=df[df['marital_status']=='married']
```

q1 = select job, avg(age) from DB where marietal_status='married' group by job

```
married.groupby('job').agg( {"age":"mean"} )
or
df[df['marital_status']=='married'].groupby('job').agg( {"age":"mean"} )

         age
job
manager   48
```

q2 = select job, avg(salary) from DB where marietal_status='married' group by job

```
married.groupby('job').agg( {"salary":"mean"} )

         salary
job
manager    9000
```

You can flatten the table by resetting the index

```
df[df['marital_status']=='married'].groupby('job').agg( {"age":"mean"} ).reset_index()

       job  age
0  manager   48
```

output the two stats together:

```
df[df['marital_status']=='married'].groupby('job').agg( {"age":"mean","salary":"mean"} ).reset_index()

       job  age  salary
0  manager   48    9000
```

Answer (score 1):

After you create your dataframe (df), the following command builds your desired table.

```
df.groupby(['job', 'country_origin','degree'])[['age', 'salary']].agg([np.mean,max,sum])
```

Here is a complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['job']=['tech','coder','admin','admin','admin','tech']
df['country_origin']=['japan','japan','US','US','India','India']
df['degree']=['cert','bs','bs','ms','bs','cert']
df['age']=[22,23,30,35,40,28]
df['salary']=[30,50,60,90,65,40]
df.groupby(['job', 'country_origin','degree'])[['age', 'salary']].agg([np.mean,max,sum])
```